# IdentityServer4 Client prop Claim can not set in MongoDB

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to use this to insert a new client to MongoDB Collection `Client`:

```
                new Client
            {
                ClientId = "clientB",
                // 没有交互性用户，使用 clientid/secret 实现认证。
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                // 用于认证的密码
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secretB".Sha256())
                },
                // 客户端有权访问的范围（Scopes）
                AllowedScopes = { "api1" },
                Claims=new List<Claim>(){
                     new Claim( JwtClaimTypes.Role,"superadmin")
                }
            }
```

but I got this:

[image: clientB MongoDB raw data]

As you can see, the property `Claims` can not be set, why?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands, log files, configuration or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: @CKE Thanks for the remind.I am working on .

Answer (score 0):

The Identity token is returned from the IdentityServer but the  claims were not included.
IdentityServer does not include identity claims (except sub) in the identity token, unless you specifically ask for it, (not recommended)
ie like this...

```
new Client {
    ClientId = "myclient",
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,    //not a good idea
...
```

Here is a bit of extra info on the subject. By default, IdentityServer doesn't include identity claims in the identity token. It is allowed by setting the AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken setting on the client configuration to true. But it is not recommended. The initial identity token is returned from the authorization endpoint via front‑channel communication either through a form post or through the URI. If it's returned via the URI and the token becomes too big, you might hit URI length restrictions, which are still dependent on the browser. Most modern browsers don't have issues with long URIs, but older browsers like Internet Explorer might. This may or may not be of concern to you. Looks like my project is similar to yours. Good luck.